# Javascript regular expression issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I have more strings split by 2 spaces , something like:

```
abc  adfdfg  aefdf  xcv
   ^^      ^^     ^^
```

What is the correct regular expression to retrieve that strings.
Thanks.

LE: what i tried is : `split(/[a-zA-Z\-]\s{2}/);` and it is not working

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: ... like Googling `javascript split string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your string to be declared using `var string = 'abc  adfdfg  aefdf  xcv'`. Then use:

`string = string.split(/\s{2,}/);` returns a list of substrings, split by at least two white-space characters (including tabs and newlines). If you only want to split spaces, use  (space) instead of `\s`.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to break that into separate words is like this (requires exactly two spaces):

```
var str = "abc  adfdfg  aefdf  xcv";
var words = str.split("  ");
```

`words` is now an array of words from the string.

---

If you want to split on any amount of whitespace, you can use a regular expression as the split argument:

```
var str = "abc  adfdfg  aefdf  xcv";
var words = str.split(/\s+/);
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pkUh9/

---

If you want to split on two or more units of whitespace, you can use this regular expression as the split argument:

```
var str = "abc  adfdfg  aefdf  xcv";
var words = str.split(/\s{2,}/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
'abc adfdfg aefdf xcv'.split(/\s+/)
```